# ASYNC pipe not working on BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, ethereum, behaviorsubject, async-pipe

I'm trying to use Async pipe but when i trigger some new data to my BehaviorSubject, the value is not even fetch by the subject. If i change the async pipe by a manualy subscription, i receive the value but the view still not updated. I have to use manualy detectChange for this case.

Services:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WalletService {
  ethereum: any;
  currentAccountSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  currentNetworkSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  currentProviderSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor() {
    this.ethereum = (<any>window).ethereum;
    this.checkWalletConnected().subscribe();
    this.accountChanged();
    this.networkChanged();
  }

  private accountChanged(): void {
    this.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', (accounts: string[]) => {
      if(accounts.length === 0) this.currentProviderSubject.next(null);
      console.log('accountChanged', accounts) //WORKING FINE
      this.currentAccountSubject.next(accounts);
    });
  }
}
```

Components:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  accounts$: Observable<string[]> = of([]);

  constructor(private walletService: WalletService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.accounts$ = this.walletService.currentAccountSubject.pipe(
      skip(1),
      distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev[0] === curr[0]),
      tap(wallets => console.log('wallets', wallets)), //NOT WORKING WITH ASYNC PIPE BUT WORKING WHITOUT
    )

  }
}
```

HTLM:
AppComponent:

```
<app-toolbar [accounts]="accounts$ | async"></app-toolbar>
```

ToolBarComponent:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <span>
    <img src="/assets/mySvg.svg" alt="svg" />
  </span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <ng-container *ngIf="accounts && accounts.length > 0; else btnConnect">{{accounts[0]}}</ng-container>
  <ng-template #btnConnect>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="connectToWallet()">Connect Wallet</button>
    </ng-template>
</mat-toolbar>
```

If you want to try yourself:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xkrt7c?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: What is the reason for the skip? Maybe that is conencted to the issue?

Comment: Skip the event for the initial value from BehaviorSubject

Answer (score -1):

The below line is the problem, ensure that unique value is being compared inside the `distinctUntilUnchanged`.

```
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev[0] === curr[0]), // <- problem here
```

You can try to fix it yourself if not please share a sample data for `prev` and `curr` inorder to resolve this issue and also provide the unique key inside accounts!

Comment: This is the of data i receive after 2 accounts switch. This is the console.log from the services accountChanged ['0xfb4576ae0595f4b4a3ec469f6c4dec7506380018'] &
accountChanged ['0x6d5ede35c74c3e5fa9cac91226701e95ccbd10ae']. distinctUntilUnchanged is not the issue, same behavior whitout it.

Comment: @nevradub if null is sent for prev or curr, application will give error, could you try changing it to ` distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => (prev && prev[0]) === (curr[ && curr[0]))` if not, please share a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: I just add the stackblitz to the main questions. You will need to install Metamask extention and create 2 empty wallet to the ethereum blockchain to test it. If you have some issue with the connexion of your wallet to the stackblitz, better to create an empty project in angular 14 (as where i have the issue) and to copy the files.